# Lorentz Reciprocal Theorem: Why No Pressure

Tags: fluid-dynamics, continuum-mechanics

So in my reading on the Lorentz reciprocal identity, I got lost in a step. Why can he remove the pressure term with the continuity equation? Any advice or guidance would be great!

**Pozrikidis**

[image: Pozrikidis]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the Einstein summation convention, then $$\delta_{ij}\frac{\partial u'_i}{\partial x_j}=\frac{\partial u'_i}{\partial x_i}$$If the fluid is incompressible, the latter is zero by the continuity equation.